Should I remove vinyl flooring underlayment or build up adjacent areas to make them level?
I'm currently undertaking a project to replace vinyl roll and carpet throughout my house with LVP. I've pulled up the carpet in the first room and it has vinyl roll in the hallway next to it (no transition). After pulling up the carpet I noticed there's a second layer of 1/4 subflooring or underlayment underneath the vinyl roll.


Is the best way to solve this adding a matching second layer to the rooms with carpet? If so do I need to be concerned with which way I lay it out other than not lining the seams up?

Vinyl roll/sheet/tile is very thin.
They use very smooth under layment/luan sheets to help the vinyl last.
Can remove it, add more to the other floors, or have a transition piece between floors.
If the vinyl roll has not been removed, it is possible to lay the new LVP right on top of it.

I will likely just add on to the rooms that don't have it since there is much more vinyl roll, that would need it removed, than carpet, that would need it added, throughout the house.
When doing this is there any special type of way to lay it, i.e., orientation, spacing/gaps that need to be left between pieces/walls, or any type of special securing (adhesive/specific screws?) for the second layer?

Underlayment is a surface treatment, not a structural component. As such, it's mostly important that it be fastened properly and doesn't really matter how it's oriented. That said, if you want to try and improve the stiffness of a squishy subfloor, act accordingly to take advantage of the new material.
